# Is ROS uses gcc or g++ compiler for c codes?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I have a C code which is using some C++ functions and i want to know if the ROS catkin_make uses gcc or g++ compiler ?
Or where can i change the default compilers and compiling flags.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374821/is-ros-uses-gcc-or-g++-compiler-for-c-codes?/) by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2021-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check which compiler is being used by looking at the message when you run `catkin_make`.

If you get the following message, you are probably using gcc and LLVM g++.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 4.0.0
```

ref: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages

To change the compiler and options, add the following to the CMakeList.txt file

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O2")
```

ref: https://answers.ros.org/question/56398/run-catkin-make-with-custom-compiler/?answer=156461

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-28**:
Note: *nothing* here is ROS-specific. This is all CMake.

If you want to learn more about selecting and configuring compilers which will be used by Catkin/Colcon: look up the relevant CMake documentation.

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2021-03-30**:
The problem I'm facing is that Cmake is giving an error which is the compiler can't find some of the boost libraries (boost_signals), but i am pretty sure that the boost library is well installed.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-03-31**:
This may have already been discussed in https://answers.ros.org/question/333142/boost_signals-library-not-found/. If not, please create a new question. I think we are starting to stray from the title of this question.

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2021-04-01**:
please can you tell me where can i find the tf ros package C/C++ codes because I'm only finding the include codes not source codes

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-02**:
You should create a new question. When asking a question, it is recommended that you also provide information about your OS and how you installed the tf package.